# Strike through All Textblocks inside ListView

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

How can I strike through all textblocks inside my WPF listview?  Right now I've defined a style that I have to apply to each textblock.  It looks like this

```
    <Style x:Key="orderDetailsTextBlock" TargetType="TextBlock" >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Failed">
                <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Strikethrough" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

What I want is to be able to apply this once inside the ListViewItem Style block.

I tried to do it like this

```
    <Style x:Key="ordersListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Failed">
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="Strikethrough" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>           
    </Style>
```

But this doesn't work.  Any help will appreciated.

**Update**
I updated the ListView's XAML as follows

```
    <ListView x:Name="orderDetails" AlternationCount="2" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ordersListViewItemStyle}" >
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Failed">
                    <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Strikethrough" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Статус" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock 
                                            Text="{Binding Path=Status, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                            ToolTip="{Binding Path=Message, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                            TextAlignment="Center" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Nothing happens.  What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the Style inside your `ListView.Resources` without a `Key`, and it's scope will be restricted to all `TextBlock`s inside that particular `ListView`.

For instance:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <!-- Style specific content -->
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <!-- ListView content -->
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `x:Key` of the `TextBlock` style and put it in the `ListView.Resources`, it should apply automatically then. (See remarks on [`TargetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype.aspx))